# Python subprocess command answering prompt

Tags: python, shell, process, scripting, subprocess

I am trying to call a command

```
ionic cordova prepare
```

which prompts for a "Y/N" response. I always want this to be yes. When i tried using os.system it would hang at the last part and not move onto the rest of the script. Does anyone know the right way of writing this.

This is what i tried

```
foo_proc = Popen(['ionic', 'cordova', 'prepare'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
yes_proc = Popen(['yes', 'y'], stdout=foo_proc.stdin)
foo_proc.communicate()[0]
yes_proc.wait()
```

But it just hangs on the command and doesn't seem to execute

Comment: Only *one* prompt? Why run `yes_proc` at all, then, rather than `foo_proc.communicate('y\n')` to pass a single `y` to the stdin of `foo_proc`?

Comment: You mean running
    foo_proc = Popen(['ionic', 'cordova', 'prepare'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
    foo_proc.communicate('y\n')
When i do this it seems to just skip the command. It never executes

Comment: I mean running *what*?  BTW, can't reproduce this issue when changing `['ionic', 'cordova', 'prepare']` to `['head', '-n', '1']`, which implies there's something specific to this `ionic` command going on.

Comment: The above code certainly does execute `foo_proc`. Check `foo_proc.returncode` -- you'll see it's set to a numeric value, whereas it's `None` before the program is ever run.

Comment: BTW, many well-behaved programs only prompt if stdin is a TTY, but assume they're being run in a batch mode controlled by other software (not by a user) if stdin is a non-TTY object such as a pipe. I don't know this "ionic" tool, whatever it is, but you might consider the potential for something along those lines going on. Throwing away stderr, instead of logging it -- especially when debugging errors! -- is likely to be... unhelpful to your cause.

Comment: Its the same issue actually. The code is never getting executed. So no returncode. It does when i change the the syntax a little bit though

For instance i tried
    command = 'ionic cordova prepare'
    p = Popen(command.split(), shell=True, stdin=PIPE)
    p.communicate('y\n')
    p.returncode

But my output is 'y' (as i would think it should be) then the prompt y/n - which isn't called but no return code

Comment: `proc.communicate()` doesn't return until the process has terminated -- this is explicit in its documentation. I'll need to be shown some actual evidence (ie. code I can run myself to generate the same result) to believe a contrary claim.

Answer (score 5):

As of python 3.5, the `subprocess` module introduced the high level `run` method, which returns a `CompletedProcess` object:

```
subprocess.run(['somecommand', 'somearg'], capture_output=True, text=True, input="y")
```

See documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Answer (score 2):

**This work for me:**

```py
foo_proc = Popen(['ionic', 'cordova', 'prepare'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
foo_proc.stdin.write(b"y\n")
outputlog, errorlog = foo_proc.communicate()
foo_proc.stdin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with communicating several Y/N/ to answer a script launched with subprocess... Nothing worked, I did not find any good 'clean' solution in the end, so I used a trick:
I created a bash script (launch_script.sh) where I wrote:

```
echo -e "Y\nN\nY\n" | scripttoanswer.ksh
```

in it and then used subprocess to simply launch it:

```
subprocess.run(["/home/user/dev/my_project/launch_script.sh"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Charles duffy example here,May be this can help you!!

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
foo_proc = Popen(['ionic', 'cordova', 'prepare'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
foo_proc.communicate(input='y')
```